# Fixing the animation properties

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am doing some research at the moment into creating a new maths game for primary school children where divs from 0-9 appear at random inside a container.

A question is given at the beginning. Something like, multiples of 20. The user will then have to click on the correct ones, and they will then be counted at the end and a score will be given.

I have just changed the speed in which the divs appear so that they appear for longer and more than one at a time to make the game easier for younger children.

I used "fadeIn" like so..

```
    $('#' + id).animate({
        top: newY,
        left: newX
    }, 'slow', function() {}).fadeIn(2000);
}
```

My problem is that now when I shoot the correct or incorrect number the animation is very glitchy and I cannot figure out why.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cFKHq/6/ (See version 5 to see what it was like before)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside `startplay()`, control the concurrency when calling `scramble()` , I do it with a global var named `window.cont`, so I replaced your following call:

```
play = setInterval(scramble, 1800);
```

for this one:

```
play = setInterval(function() { 
          if (window.cont){ 
              window.cont = false;
              scramble();
          }
}, 1000);
```

The var `window.cont` needs to be set globally at the start of your code, like so:

```
var miss = 0;
var hit = 0;
var target = $("#target");
window.cont = true;
```

So with `window.cont` you now can control that animations are executed one after another, without overlapping, like so:

```
$('#'+id).css({
    top: newY,
    left: newX
}).fadeIn(2000, function() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        $('#' + id).slideUp('fast');
        window.cont = true;
      }, 1500);
});
```

See working [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gnel/B4uJ4/9/embedded/result/)

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for but I also wanted for the divs to come at the same time, any idea how to do that? @Nelson

Comment: at the same time? all of the 10 divs? that would need some more refactor from your original code..

Comment: No just so they overlap in times so there is more than 1 @Nelson

Comment: @Milo-J See http://jsfiddle.net/gnel/B4uJ4/13/ for a version that shows two divs at the same time. You can adjust the window.cont var to show 3 or 4 at same time.

Comment: That's perfect, thanks. I am going to accept your answer I was just wondering if you could take it to chat and discuss another issue? Its to do with the nth-child odds and evens @Nelson

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18460/discussion-between-milo-j-and-nelson)